Filtrar por un Selector de rango en un documento Quarto
Quisiera saber si es posible crear un selector de rango con mínimo y máximo (como en Shinyhttps://shiny.posit.co/py/components/inputs/slider-range/) en una dashboard de Quarto.
El código que tengo hasta ahora es así
{ojs}


//| expandable: false

// Transpose the data to make it usable in ojs
df_t = transpose(df_ojs)

// Create a dropdown menu for Sexo with unique values
viewof SexoDropdown = Inputs.select(
  Array.from(new Set(df_t.map(d => d.Sexo))), // Ensuring unique options
  {
    label: "Sexo:"
  }
)

// Get the minimum and maximum ages for the slider
minAge = Math.min(...df_t.map(d => d.edad))
maxAge = Math.max(...df_t.map(d => d.edad))

// Create a slider for the Age
viewof AgeSlider = Inputs.range(
  [minAge, maxAge], // Min and Max age
  {
    label: "Rango etario:",
    step: 1,
    value: [minAge, maxAge] // Set the initial range to cover all ages
  }
)

// Reactively update df_t based on the selection in SexoDropdown and AgeSlider
filtered_df_t = {
  const selectedSexo = SexoDropdown;
  const [minSelectedAge, maxSelectedAge] = AgeSlider;
  return df_t.filter(d => d.Sexo === selectedSexo && d.edad >= minSelectedAge && d.edad <= maxSelectedAge);
}

// Output the filtered data as a table
Inputs.table(filtered_df_t)


Pero está dando el error TypeError: AgeSlider is not iterable

Parece que no https://github.com/observablehq/inputs?tab=readme-ov-file#range
